# kABPersonAddressCityKey undeclared problem

Tags: iphone, objective-c, geolocation, gps

I am trying to get city name based on my geo location. Problem is that I am getting compile time error from title in this method. What have I done wrong?

```
- (void)reverseGeocoder:(MKReverseGeocoder *)geocoder didFindPlacemark:(MKPlacemark *)placemark
{
    MKPlacemark * myPlacemark = placemark;
    // with the placemark you can now retrieve the city name
    NSString *city = [myPlacemark.addressDictionary objectForKey:(NSString*) kABPersonAddressCityKey];
}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This constant is from AddressBook framework, although it is used outside of it as well. Try importing AddressBook header to fix your problem:

```
#import <AddressBook/AddressBook.h>
```

Answer (score 0):

Since iOS9 you have to use CNPostalAddressCityKey constant.